# Accessing Information from a MenuButton populated with CheckMenuItems (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

I'm writing a program with javafx and need to have a drop down box where I am able to select multiple options and have a function applied to each option selected after pressing a "submit" button, but I am running into trouble with distinguishing which options are selected after the "Submit" button has been clicked.

It wont allow me to apply any methods from the CheckMenuItem class such as .isSelected() to an observableList because the List seems to be filled with MenuItems, not CheckMenuItems but when I created the MenuButton, I used an observableList of CheckMenuItems.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
public final ObservableList<MenuItem> getItems()
```

MenuButton getItems return ObservableList of MenuItem , you have to explicitly cast to CheckMenuItem and then call methods related to CheckMenuItem.

Sample Code :

```
public class CheckMenuItemTest extends Application {

    private ObservableList<CheckMenuItem> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        HBox root = new HBox();
       final  MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton();
        CheckMenuItem item1 = new CheckMenuItem("item1");
        CheckMenuItem item2 = new CheckMenuItem("item2");
        CheckMenuItem item3 = new CheckMenuItem("item3");
        CheckMenuItem item4 = new CheckMenuItem("item4");
        list.addAll(item1,item2,item3,item4);
        menuButton.getItems().addAll(list);
        Button button = new Button("Submit");
        root.getChildren().addAll(menuButton,button);
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                for(MenuItem item : menuButton.getItems()) {
                    CheckMenuItem checkMenuItem = (CheckMenuItem) item;
                    if(checkMenuItem.isSelected()) {
                        System.out.println("Selected item :" + checkMenuItem.getText());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,300,300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```